# How to make SeekBar thumb looks like youtube android app's

Tags: android, youtube, seekbar, android-styles

I try to put SeekBar thumb drawable outside background. I want to make it seems like this:

[image: Thumb outside Seekbar]

This is screenshot from Youtube android client.

Can somebody help me?